# how to select from two tables with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

There is Two tables :

Table 1 :

```
 id = 0      name=JOHN           speciality =dentist  
 id = 1      name=ABY            speciality= dentist  
 id = 2      name = SARA         speciality= cardiologist
```

,...
  Table 2 :

```
 id = 0    name = JOHN           city=paris
 id = 1    name = ABY            city=tokio
 id = 1    name = SARA           city=london

 $city='pa';  

 $speciality='dentist';
```

(this two variables are coming from a searching form that user has enterend)

I want to say this :

```
select * FROM Table 1 WHERE speciality=$speciality AND city LIKE %$city% (from Table2) ;
```

what should I say ?
(very obvious that id are the same for each row of both table ,and each id represents a person)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
   select t1.* FROM Table 1 as t1,table2 as t2 WHERE t1.speciality='$speciality' AND t1.city  LIKE %$city%  and t1.name=t2.name;
```

if row id is same for both table then:

```
   select t1.* FROM Table 1 as t1,table2 as t2 WHERE t1.speciality='$speciality' AND t1.city  LIKE %$city%  and t1.name=t2.name and t1.id=t2.id ;
```